# How are VARCHAR columns implemented? Are they actual character arrays?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, memory-management, database-design

If I create a column of type `VARCHAR (50)` on a table and add rows, do the rows actually have 50 characters (or 51 if there's a null-terminating character)? In other words, if I deploy my application and the user input that goes to that column ends up only being strings of no more than 10 characters, am I wasting 80% of memory?

Comment: No, that's why it's 'var' char. You waste a byte - compared with a char string of the full length - well actually it gets a bit more complicated than that, but generally, these days there's really no need to use char unless all the strings are of uniform length. I think the manual covers this one quite well

Comment: @Strawberry that assumes you are not using MyISAM (and maybe some other storage engines).  If you are using one of those, you have to weight the cost of the wasted space against the speed costs from rows of varying length, and (if your data model allows DELETEs) possible fragmentation.

Comment: @uueerdo I wasn't aware that different engines behaved differently in this respect. I think the speed benefit of char is maintained only so long as the whole row is of constant length. But yes, I think it's more efficient to store y/n flags as char(1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CHARACTER SET**

In addition to what is said by the others, the `CHARACTER SET` for the column needs factoring in.

`ascii` uses 1 byte for 1 character.
`latin1` uses 1 byte for 1 character.
`utf8` uses 1, 2, or 3 bytes for 1 character.
`utf8mb4` uses 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes for 1 character.

The number on the declaration is *characters*, not *bytes*.

`CHAR(10)` can hold the widest 10 characters in the given `CHARACTER SET`.  For utf8mb4, it will always occupy 40 bytes.  This is a reason to either

- never use `CHAR`, always use `VARCHAR`, and/or
- explicitly say `CHARACTER SET ascii` for things like Y/N, M/F, country code, postal code, SSN, hex strings, etc.

`VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` will handle up to 10 characters, whether it is 1-byte English characters or 3- and 4-byte Chinese characters.

**Temp table in a SELECT**

A `SELECT` that does certain things like `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` or 'UNION' *may* decide it needs to build a "temp" table for the intermediate processing.  If it does, it first considering building the table in RAM using the MEMORY engine.  If so, then it turns all `VARCHARs` into `CHARs` for the processing.  It is vary common to see `last_name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8`.  But when one of these temp tables is used, that becomes 765 bytes per row.  This is not very efficient.  How often have you seen a last_name that was 255 characters long?  So

- Don't always use `(255)`; make it something reasonable; and
- Use ascii/latin1 when appropriate.

Comment: In some newer versions, `CHAR(10)` will take a minimum of 10 _bytes_, not _characters_.  That's better than 40, but still says that `VARCHAR` is better (where applicable).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to answer your question is thru comparison.

The CHAR and VARCHAR types are similar, but differ in the way they are stored and retrieved. As of MySQL 5.0.3, they also differ in maximum length and in whether trailing spaces are retained.

For example:

```
DECLARE CHARARRAY CHAR(30) = 'TEST' -- RESULT IS 'TEST..<30 - 4 SPACES>' (WITH TRAILING SPACES)
```

on the other hand:

```
DECLARE VARCHARARRAY VARCHAR(30) = 'TEST' -- RESULT IS 'TEST' (WITHOUT TRAILING SPACES)
```

The CHAR and VARCHAR types are declared with a length that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store. For example, CHAR(30) can hold up to 30 characters.

The length of a CHAR column is fixed to the length that you declare when you create the table. The length can be any value from 0 to 255. When CHAR values are stored, they are right-padded with spaces to the specified length. When CHAR values are retrieved, trailing spaces are removed.

Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used

In contrast to CHAR, VARCHAR values are stored as a 1-byte or 2-byte length prefix plus data. The length prefix indicates the number of bytes in the value. A column uses one length byte if values require no more than 255 bytes, two length bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes.

**Conclusion**

If you want to optimize your database, I would suggest you use `varchar` rather than a char. The sizes of the field may vary depending on field usage. If you are starting to have a design yourself database, [this link](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm) might help you.

Reference:

[The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

Comment: Strictly speaking, length is the number of bytes - some character sets include multi byte characters.

Comment: @Strawberry strictly strictly speaking, length is the number of *characters*.  A utf8 `CHAR(1)` is three allocated bytes constrained to hold 1 character max.